# How to get other row value while grouping query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me explain with example,

```
id  firstname lastname Mark
--------------------------------
1   arun        prasanth  40
2   ann         antony      45
3   sruthy      abc          41
6   new         abc          47
1   arun        prasanth  45
1   arun        prasanth 49
2   ann        antony     49
```

and AS IS, if I query like:

```
select count(*) as count, firstname, lastname, Mark
       from tableA
       group by id
       order by count desc
```

then in the result, 3 arun ~~ row will be on the top. I have to keep this order(count desc)

But I want to search  each Mark score which are 49 45 40. 
I want to put result in $sql and use it like $sql['(every mark score for ann)'], how do I do that?

Comment: Post your expected output as well.

Comment: Note because you are grouping by `id`. its only by co-incidence that firstname, lastname can exist in your answer. With MySQL-8.0 the defaul SQL mode will error on this. See [this reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). You may need `SELECT ANY_VALUE(firstname), ANY_VALUE(lastname)...` which indicates that your data isn't normalised (i.e. user id/names in a separate table).

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: And show us what the desired result would look like

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, firstname, lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(mark) AS Mark
       FROM tableA
       GROUP BY id
       ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

This will show mark like '40, 45, 49' with comma. If you don't want comma, add `SEPARATOR` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, firstname, lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(mark SEPARATOR ' ') AS Mark
       FROM tableA
       GROUP BY id
       ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

This will use a space(`' '`) as separator instead of comma like '40 45 49'. Of course you can define any separator you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use Having clause on your query for result

```
select count(*) as count, firstname, lastname, Mark
       from tableA
       group by id having by firstname = 'ann'
       order by count desc
```

Comment: Thx! just my question was bad since I had to use it all case not just for 'ann'. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original data, use `count()` or a subquery in the `order by`:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
order by count(*) over (partition by id) desc,
         id
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a subquery instead:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
order by (select count(*) from tableA a2 where a2.id = a.id) desc,
         id
```